# Autobahn: User status like Online, Offline

Tags: autobahn, autobahnws

Since Autobahn is isolated from the application server,

How can we track the online or offline status of the user ?

Answer (score 0):

[Crossbar.io](https://crossbar.io/) provides so-called [*meta events*](https://crossbar.io/docs/Session-Metaevents-and-Procedures/) which are fired when WAMP sessions join or leave the router.